# How to take only a specific object from JSON using rest assured

Tags: java, junit5, rest-assured

I write API tests. In response, I get a JSON file in which I need to take only the object (what is inside "Model") and pass it to a string. Using java, rest-assured.

This is my test

```
public static String returnCity(String CityId) {
        String string = "";
        Response response = given().spec(returnRequest(token))
                .when().get(Configuration.baseUrl + "/api/v1/city/" + CityId)
                .then()
                .log().all()
                .contentType(JSON)
                .assertThat()
                .statusCode(200)
                .extract().response();
        string = response.body("Model");
        String city = JsonPath.read(string, "$.Model").toString();
        return city;

    }
```

this is an example json file i get in response.

```
{
    "Model": {
        "Id": 1489,
        "Name": "New-York",
        "CountryId": 14,
        "OraId": 88,
        "DistrictId": 6,
        "Lat": 25.158855465,
        "Long": 7.4703558,
        "GoogleGeoId": "",
        "TimezoneId": 3,
        "AreaId": 4,
        "District": {
            "Id": 12,
            "Name": "Uganda",
            "OraId": 51,
            "Cities": null,
            "CountryId": 9,
            "OraParishId": 0
        },
        "Area": {
            "Id": 4,
            "Name": "New-Orlean",
            "DistrictId": 14,
            "CountryId": 88,
            "OraId": 666
        },
        "IsShowArea": false,
        "StoreId": 9,
        "DeliveryPointsNumber": 0,
        "MajorOrder": 1
    }
}
```

Comment: What field do you want to extract?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I need to extract everything that is inside "Model" and convert this to string

Answer (score 0):

To extract the "Model" object from the JSON response and convert it to a string using Java and Rest-Assured, you can modify your code as follows:

```
String city = response.jsonPath().getString("Model");
    return city;
}
```

Hope this helps!!!